# Codeigniter - routing to the controller if it exists, if not use dafault

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I have set up my routes like so:

```
$route[':any'] = "main";
$route['products/(:any)'] = "products/product/$1";
```

For example **www.mysite.com/something** goes to main controller, where I deal with **"something"**. 
With products I deal in similar way.

But as you can see after that I have to write down all the other controllers with methods that I wish to be used instead of main controller. Is there a way to make it automatically detect if the controller exists use the controller and not the default **"main"**?

```
$route['products'] = "products";
$route['admin/user/login'] = "admin/user/login";
$route['admin/user/logout'] = "admin/user/logout";
$route['admin/migrations'] = "admin/migrations";
$route['admin/dashboard'] = "admin/dashboard";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't take any credit for it as I found it on a blog somewhere, but I use the following code in my routes.php, in your case I would place it above the `$route[':any'] = "main";`

```
$controller_dir = opendir(APPPATH."controllers");

while (($file = readdir($controller_dir)) !== false) {

    if (substr($file, -4) == ".php" ) {

        $route[substr($file, 0, -4)."(.*)"] = substr($file, 0, -4)."$1";

    } elseif (substr($file, -5) == ".php/") {

        $route[substr($file, 0, -5)."(.*)"] = substr($file, 0, -5)."$1";

    }
}
```

Should I need to override any of them, or have any unique routes, I place those at the top of the routes.php file, above this code.

Comment: Thanks Jeemsu that seems to work - I edited your answer adding routes for controller/method and controller/method/var1. Even though it works, it seems a bit hacky.. anyways thanks again.
@Petah - here we go again :)

Comment: hi, why not use this $route['404_override'] = 'notfound'; and create notfound controller and make all code easy and flexiable.

Comment: @wasim Seems a bit hacky to me, why use a route specifically meant for catching 404 errors to route all your applications logic?

Comment: actually if a controller not found then logically we should override in 404, there we can controller like, if controller not found but URL is blah blah then do blah things else do 404 ... so we still have 404 in control. beside that its more convenient than using custom php

Comment: The 404 catch all should be a last resort. It would be logical to keep all your routes in the routes.php, thats where I would expect to find them as a developer approaching someone else's codeigniter project. At the end of the day, do whatever you think is the most logical, everyone has their own approach to development.