# routing issue in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have index controller as default with index method.

```
class Index extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
  }
  public function index(){
     // main page of website...
  }
}
```

Now, If there is a parameter in index method, then I want render different view. something like this:

```
 public function index($username){
   if($username!=''){
      // render page 1...
   }
   else{
      // main page of website...
   }
}
```

when I pass the parameter, it says: `The page you requested was not found.`

**EDIT**

I tried by updating routes in `routes.php` file:

```
$route['index/(:any)'] = 'index/$1';
```

I want user to access their profile in this URL: `example.com/username`

Right now, I need to type: `example.com/index/index/username`

Comment: yeah I'm going to delete my answer - i'm wondering if you can name a controller index???

Comment: actually, controller name and method name are same. (`index`)

Comment: Reserved Name!! https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/reserved_names.html So just call your controller something else.

Comment: its of course ok to have the method be called index()

Comment: @Ronak Patel see my edited answer

Comment: I got the solution from http://stackoverflow.com/a/15153860/3067928

Thank you for your efforts guys.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended using a controller name "Index"
Still if you want Make sure your file name is index.php.
and put this code

```
class Index extends CI_Controller
{

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }
  public function index($username="")
  {

    if($username!='')
    {
        echo "user name found";//do your stuff
    }
    else
    {
        echo "username not found";//do your stuff
    }
  }
}
```

Now put this code to your route.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "index"; 
$route['(:any)']="index/index/$1";
```

Now you can access this way `example.com/username` and `example.com`

Comment: It's not working. I tried just like this before placing routing rules.

Comment: please put your full controller and the link you trying to.

Comment: I have modified the answer and it is tested

Comment: is there any way to remove those 2 indexes. i want straightforward URL. `example.com/username`. That's it

Comment: to do that use these rules at route.php `$route['default_controller'] = "index";` `$route['(:any)']="index/index/$1";`

Comment: also make sure your controller is like the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65245/discussion-between-ronak-patel-and-shaiful-islam).

Comment: You are right. But, it will crash my application. and other controllers and methods.

Comment: Yes you will lose other controller access if you try to use index controller that way
because codeigniter cannot understand you are trying to access a username or a controller

Answer (score 0):

Write Code Like

Controller -

```
class index extends  CI_Controller 
{
    function _construct() 
    {
     parent::__construct();
    }

   public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('views_file');
    }
}
```

**And update route.php With :-**

```
$route['index/(:any)'] = 'index/index/$1';
```

**View Must be :**

```
<a href="index/<?php echo $username ?>"> username </a>
```