# Give first priority to controller instead of routes rules

Tags: codeigniter

Is it possible in CI to first check in controller.. If controller not found then only check in routes rule?

What we want is,

We have an URL with two segments  i.e testctl/testmethod, Now we want 1 dynamic URL which also have 2 segments. So for that we want to set Route rule like **$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = ctl/method/$1/$2**.
Because of this rule all URL's with 2 segments are loading ctl/method/$1/$2.

Comment: So then you'd write a rule for testctl/testmethod to go to testctl/testmethod Before your any any route.

Comment: but we have too many controllers like that.. So we have to write rule for each. its become too lengthy

Comment: Is there any pattern to those? You can use regex expressions. But just wondering, how many different urls are you going to have to requires your any any in the first place?

Comment: If you are pointing just about everything at ctl/method/$1/$2, cant that determine where it ends up?

Comment: There is no limit for any any url as it will dynamic. We want dynamic url for each product with its one attribute and name of product.. like domain/attribut_value/product_name

Comment: This might get you started - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153559/codeigniter-routing-to-the-controller-if-it-exists-if-not-use-dafault

Comment: Thank you so much @TimBrownlaw Needed some modification in code but it worked perfect as we want...

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using route rules if the method provides default values for the arguments.

```
public function testfunc($arg1 = FALSE, $arg2 = FALSE)
{
    if($arg1)
    {
        echo "$arg1 ";
    }
    if($arg2)
    {
        echo "$arg2 ";
    }
    echo date("F j, Y, g:i:s a");
}
```

If that method is in the `Welcome` controller then the URL `http://example.com/welcome` produces output containing only the date.

The URL `http://example.com/welcome/hello` produces

```
hello January 24, 2018, 9:39:08 am
```

The URL `http://example.com/welcome/hello/world` produces

```
hello world January 24, 2018, 9:39:08 am
```

The URL `http://example.com/welcome/0/world` produces

```
world January 24, 2018, 9:39:08 am
```

The point is that the method responds based on whether or not arguments are passed.

Not a single route needs to be defined for the above to work.

Comment: Thanks for your time.. But it will not help us as we don't want any 3rd/static segment in URL

Comment: You don't seem to understand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. Because of the url scheme you have chosen, you have circumvented the path of least resistance in Code Igniter, and you cannot get out of this without writing more code somewhere.

If you have other rules that are falling into that pattern, then you need to either define routes for them, or use a controller switch to intelligently parse the actual URL and then call other methods as needed before falling through to the logic for your products.

This next idea sounds like it will not work for you, but other solutions could involve changing your URL schema entirely, using a distinct term somewhere such as `domain/product/attribut_value/product_name` so your route would be `$route['product/(:any)/(:any)']`.